# Neo4j HA scale out scenario

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, neo4j

Is it possible or even feasible to start Neo4j HA with one master and add slave in high traffic time with some sort of load balancing?

From Neo4j Doc :

> Neo4j HA requires a quorum in order to serve write load. What this
>   means is that a strict majority of the servers in the cluster need to
>   be online in order for the cluster to accept write operations.

Is one master with no slave available, yet can create a quorum?

Comment: The documentation describes arbiter instances to resolve the 2 node cluster problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a master then you have no HA. You're just not resilient to failovers. If you have a master/slave setup then as John mentioned you can run an Arbiter instance that is just used to determine the coordinator based on the quorum.
To answer your question, I think you'd need to have a Powershell script that would create a neo4j.properties and neo4j-server.properties file on a new server, copy over the necessary files, and start the service. You'll also need a way to poll the HA cluster in order to get all participating servers in order to create the properties files.